# How to I build a go package for the current OS but output it to a specified folder?

Tags: go, build

When I run `go build main.go`, the compiler will output a binary for the current OS in that same folder. In this case I would get a `main.exe` or a `main` for OSX or Linux.

If I specify an output it will build omit the file extension on Windows machines.

```
go build -o ./bin/myproject main.go
```

Because of the lack of a file extension, you're unable to run  the outputted binary on Windows without renaming it.

How do I build a go project, specifying the output folder and getting a binary named appropriately for the OS on the other side?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the logic of the `.exe` extension in a script. Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

output="./bin/myproject"


if [ -n "$GOOS" ] && [ "$GOOS" = "windows" ]; then
    output+='.exe'
fi

go build -o $output main.go
```

If you call it `build.sh`. You can invoke it:

```
bash build.sh # for using the `GOOS` defined in your environment
GOOS=windows bash build.sh # for building windows binaries (with `.exe` extension)
```